# How to add single quotes to each string in a variable?

Tags: shell

I am passing variable `$$PSTCMT` to a script as an argument:

```
test.sh $$PSTCMT
```

in the script the value is show as below:

```
PSTCMT1=$1
echo PSTCMT1
```

the output is:

```
abc,def,fgh
```

I want to replace above as below

```
PSTCMT ='abc','def','fgh'
```

`echo $PSTCMT` will give below output as

```
'abc','def','fgh'
```

Comment: Do you really mean to use two `$$` before your variable `$$PSTCMT`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in BASH then you can do:

```
pstcmt1='abc,def,fgh'

pstcmt="'${pstcmt1//,/\',\'}'"

echo "$pstcmt"

'abc','def','fgh'
```

Without BASH you can use `sed`:

```
pstcmt="'$(sed "s/,/','/g" <<< "$pstcmt1")'"
```